# tox pidgin plugin for Ubuntu

Tags: ppa, pidgin, tox

I would like to add the tox plugin in pidgin.

There is only a really complicated tutorial how to create it yourself at https://wiki.tox.im/Tox_Pidgin_Protocol_Plugin

I would prefer an automatic installation somehow, maybe a PPA or a complete install script that will do the stuff on that tutorial